# jquery click event handler firing on second click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have a HTML button which is doing the form submit part for me. It gets triggered on the second click.

**This is probably because of the parsley js library. If I remove parsley code it works fine.**

Here is the jquery code

```
    $('#upload-profile-button').on('click', function(e) {
    $("#upload-profile-form").parsley().validate();
    $("#upload-profile-form").parsley().on('form:validate', function (formInstance) {
        var isFormValid = formInstance.isValid();
        if(isFormValid){
    e.preventDefault();
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#upload-profile-button').html('Uploading...');
    var fd = new FormData($("#upload-profile-form")[0]);
    $.ajax({
        type : 'POST',
        url : '/mbatch/batch/uploadBatch',
        data : fd,
        processData : false,
        contentType : false,
        beforeSend : function() {

        },
        success : function(response) {
            if (response.data.fetchTpodSuccess == true) {
                window.location.href= "/mbatch/batch/listBatch";
            } else {
                new PNotify({
                    title: 'Notice',
                    text: response.message,
                    type: 'error',
                    styling: 'bootstrap3'
                });
                    $('#upload-profile-button').html('Submit');
            }
        },
        error : function(data) {
            new PNotify({
                title: 'Notice',
                text: JSON.parse(data.responseText).message,
                type: 'error',
                styling: 'bootstrap3'
            });
                $('#upload-profile-button').html('Submit');
        }
    });
}
             });
});
```

And here is the HTML snippet

```
    <button id="upload-profile-button" type="button"
                                class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
```

If I use button `type = "submit"` and change my handler to submit it does not work even after using `preventDefaut()`.

Any leads would be highly appreciated

Comment: Try to change click event listener like this: `$(class_of_parent_div).on('click', '#upload-profile-button',  function(e) { ... }`

Comment: Provide a [mcve] demo that reproduces problem. Nothing in code shown would suggest such a problem but we don't have the full context of where you call this code. Perhaps it is being called inside another event handler? Or before element exists?

Comment: Need more context because look like a problem not in this piece of code.
Fast suggestion that you bind current click handler after first click
Thanks!

Comment: @charlietfl 

I have similar click event handlers on other buttons also and I am using a single js file for 7-8 actions.
This handler is surrounded by $(document).ready(function() { });

Comment: What makes you certain it only works 2nd click? Where is demo that reproduces this?

Comment: I got it, **This is probably because of the parsley js library. If I remove parsley code it works fine.**
Any idea??